# Can I lock a 4GB or larger memory block by calling SetFileIoOverlappedRange multiple times?

Tags: windows, file, winapi, overlapped-io

Since the `Length` parameter of [`SetFileIoOverlappedRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365540(v=vs.85).aspx) is `ULONG` only, how can I lock a 4GB or larger memory block?

Say I allocate a contiguous 4 GB memory block to be used in overlapped I/O and call `SetFileIoOverlappedRange` twice, once for each half of the block. Both calls return a success (non-zero) status code. Are the calls additive, resulting in locking the whole 4 GB block? Or does the second call "override" the first? How can I tell?

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365540.aspx) points out, that *"after a range is associated with a file handle, it cannot be disassociated."*

Comment: @IInspectable Does that mean that the calls are additive? How can I check? Thanks!

Comment: Same kind of limitation that exists in MapViewOfFile(), the view cannot be larger than 4GB.  Something structural inside the kernel, no idea why it exists.

Comment: @HansPassant - ZwMapViewOfSection no limitation for 4Gb on x64 system

Comment: @HansPassant But `dwNumberOfBytesToMap` in [MapViewOfFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761(v=vs.85).aspx) is declared as `SIZE_T`.

Answer (score 0):

> Say I allocate a contiguous 4 GB memory block to be used in overlapped I/O and call `SetFileIoOverlappedRange` twice

I understand the range is intended for the `OVERLAPPED` struct, not for the data buffer.

(In reality, for the `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` struct. See [`FileIoStatusBlockRangeInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ne-wdm-_file_information_class).)

You probably don't need or have 4GB of `OVERLAPPED` structures.